# How to set CURLOPT_USERPWD, in guzzle 3.9

Tags: guzzle

I am trying to migrate the following to follow restful web service using guzzle 3.9

```
$url = Input::get('company');
            $fid='/tradingAccounts';//sample fid
            $url = $url.$fid;
            $name = Input::get('username');
            $password = Input::get('password');
            $baseurl = $url.'?&format=json';

            //SAGE USERNAME & PASSWORD
            $username = $name;
            $password = $password;


            //initiaize
            $ch = curl_init();

            //set options
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $baseurl);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            //execute
            $result = curl_exec($ch);

            //close curl session / free resources
            curl_close($ch);

            // doing a substring as there are 3 weird characters being passed back from IIS in front of the string
            $json = json_decode(substr($result, 3, strlen($result)), true);
```

this code works fine but I would like to use a more restful method I have tried several different ways to do this but I keep getting [status code] 401 [reason phrase] Unauthorized this is what I have tried

```
    $username = "MANAGER";
    $password = "";

    $client = new \Guzzle\Service\Client('http://localhost:5493/sdata/accounts50/GCRM/');
    //$client->getCurlOptions()->set(CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password );
    $request = $client->get("-/$usernames");
    $request->setAuth('username', 'password');
    echo $request->getUrl();
    $response = $request->send();

    dd($response);
```

Comment: Now that I have reread my question I have solved the problem with the following "$client->setDefaultOption('auth', array($username, $password, 'Basic'));" thank you again for all that have spent any time on this question I misread/understood the docs I typed 'username' instead of $username sent me into a tail spin

Comment: Thank you for coming back to answer this @Artful_dodger